# .Net CAD:Get file path of xref

Tags: c#, cad

How to get path of external reference use C#? I have a blockreference which is from external reference,I want to get the path of its reference file.How to get that? Please help me, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find a method which can solve the problem, use    `BlockTableRecord.GetXrefDatabase().Filename` 
can get the absolute path of the reference file.